# create a load balancer and radius authentication under linux

Tags: linux, load-balancing, centos6, freeradius

i have a centos 6 server working as a gateway receiving two internet connection from 2 isp, what i need to do is to load balance those two connection and forward the traffic to a third network card into the internal network 
i also need to use Radius server to perform network authentication for the users.

solution already tried:
 i tried to create a bridge between the two input connection, it worked but i'm not able to perform traffic control 
 i also tried to install FreeRadius

my question is:

1- is it possible to perform the load balancing from the FreeRadius mean that i can only use it for the whole solution

2- if not can anyone please guide me to a solution or a utility to perform such task

P.S i can't use a dedicated Firewall such as ZeroShell or EndianFirewall i need to implement the solution under Centos 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create pools of home servers and forward requests between them, see `raddb/proxy.conf`.